# How to connect to an IPsec server through a Nginx UDP stream reverse proxy?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

Here's the thing, I just want to use a jump server to speed up the connections to my IPsec server. So I configured Nginx to pass UDP packets as follows.

```
stream {
    # ...
    server {
        listen 500 udp;
        proxy_pass example.com:500;
        # ...
    }

    server {
        listen 4500 udp;
        proxy_pass example.com:4500;
        # ...
    }
    # ...
}
```

But I can't connect to my IPsec server through my jump server. So, I'd like to know, is this stuff not allowed now? If so, is it caused by the IPsec protocol or just the limitation of the [hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn) that I used to configure my IPsec server?

Comment: Are you able to use the VPN without using nginx as reverse proxy?
Or have you solved your problem?

Comment: I met my needs by using socat. So, I still can't get Nginx to work here.